# How to fix GNOME bar tingle while recording with OBS?

Tags: nvidia, gnome, graphics, video-recording

I am facing a problem while dragging or on opening a window while recording with OBS. Generally it works great on KDE Plasma, but when I use GNOME with Wayland disabled, this problem occurs. If I enable Wayland, then I am not able to see my desktop the next time. I'm using NVIDIA driver version 470.86.

In this image, the top bar automatically comes up:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Here, the top bar is removed and the Files window gets smashed at top:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Both images are of same recording and it doesn't look good. How can I fix this issue?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Switching to Wayland fix this problem..........

Comment: In your question you say that you cannot switch to  Wayland because you are not able to see the desktop after that, but in your comment you say that switching to Wayland fixes your problem. What's the case here? Can you clarify it please?

Comment: I have uninstalled nvidia